# How to generate DesignData for a CollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionview, listcollectionview, design-data

I have a DataGrid in xaml that takes its data from a ListCollectionView coming from the ViewModel.

How can I create a DesignData file that fills the ListCollectionView? As the ListCollectionView constructor has one parameter (the list) I don't know how to create the ListCollectionView in the DesignData xaml file.

If I have the following xaml:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
```

And the following designData:

```
   <ParameterEditor:ParameterEditorViewModel.Parameters>
        <ParameterEditor:ParameterViewModel Group="Parameter Group 1" Index="Pn001" Address="3001.001" Description="This is a test parameter 1" Value="100" DriveValue="200" Default="50" Range="0 to 400" Unit="A" />
        <ParameterEditor:ParameterViewModel Group="Parameter Group 1" Index="Pn002" Address="3001.010" Description="This is a test parameter 2" Value="200" DriveValue="300" Default="40" Range="0 to 100" Unit="B" />
    </ParameterEditor:ParameterEditorViewModel.Parameters>
```

Everything works.

If I change the xaml to:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedParameters}">
```

And GroupedParameters is a ListCollectionView, how can I create the DesignData?